# Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() NOT working on mobile devices

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile, triggers

I am using an `onOpen` function to log the user's email address when a sheet is opened

Works fine when user is using a PC (Chrome or Safari)

But when user is on a mobile device email address is not logged (Chrome or Safari)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: If users are registered, there should not be any difference between PC or mobile. Have you verified that users are registered?

Comment: Are they viewing it in mobile view or`url/htmlview`? If so, `onOpen` won't run.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with on open? Use the appropriate APIs, like Drive Activity API or Admin SDK.

Comment: Thanks, any guidance/documation on doing this ?